# Jquery How to put text into separate span after pasting it

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to put into separate spans the text I PASTE into Textarea

here's my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#span").click(function() {
  alert("1. all words into separate span, 2. all words gone after that ");

$('#words').each(function(){
      var words = $(this).text().split(" ");
      var total = words.length;
    


      $(this).empty();
      for (index = 0; index < total; index ++){
          $(this).append($("<span /> ").text(words[index]));
      }
      
     
  });
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="" value="Click" id="span"> <br><br>

<textarea id="words"   autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" >It works only when I put text in here, not when I paste it</textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bpreq129/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time when asking a question please post a helpful descriptive title, and try to be a more descriptive. Just pasting your code in and saying here do this for me will get you a negative response. Thoroughly explain what you have tried and what you are trying to do. Next time you ask a question.

To help you out though with you current dilemma you can try something like this.

```
$("#span").click(function() {
  alert("1. all words into separate span, 2. all words gone after that ");
  var textArea = $('#words');
  var arrayOfWords = textArea.val().split(" ");
  var wordsInSpans = '';
  $.each(arrayOfWords, function(i, word){
    console.log(word) // you can do anything you want with the word in here
        wordsInSpans += '<span>' + word + '</span>';
  })

  $('body').append(wordsInSpans);
  textArea.val(''); // This will set the value to blank
});
```

good luck with what you are trying to build

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect.$('#words') selector is used for just one object and is id selector.
You should specify same class for all spans and changed your selector like this :

> $('.words').

Comment: @PrincessKawaii your welcome.If it helped you please mark it as answer.Thanks